# Search API path make SEO friendly

Tags: 7, views, uri, search

I am using **Search API**. I make a view of all the indexed entities and uses **Taxonomy term** as **Contextual Filter**. But the path of view is not SEO friendly. The path is like **http://www.example.com/en/Real%20Estate**.

I want to make this path SEO friendly and convert this **space(%20) to dash**.
In views I am getting configuration "**Convert dashes into spaces**" for contextual filter.

I tried to alter the views  and implement **hook_views_pre_render, hook_views_post_render, hook_views_post_build and hook_views_post_execute**. This time it is not showing the results.

Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Facet Pretty Paths module to the rescue https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi_pretty_paths

Comment: I think Facet Pretty Paths module is only used to make changes in the parameters of facets in URL.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do that with the following code:

```
/**
  * Implements hook_views_pre_view().
  */
 function hook_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
   /* Search page view */
   if ($display_id == 'search_page' && !empty($args[0])) {
     $args[0] = strtr($args[0], '-', ' ');
   }
}
```

You should also adjust the search form ofcourse..